# Oracle SQL - Count number of appearance of text in a group by expression, if >= 1 text, else another_text

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate

I want to make a select statement to have an overview of the status of each product. The status of a product can either be `OK` or `NOT_OK` and a product can be tested multiple times. I want to have the "worst" status for each product: I want to have `NOT_OK` if the product has already been tested at least once as `NOT_OK` and else `OK`.

---

Here is a little data sample:

```
PRODUCT | STATUS    | DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
--------+-----------+--------------------------------
A       | NOT_OK    | AAA
A       | OK        | AAA
B       | OK        | BBB
B       | OK        | BBB
B       | OK        | BBB
C       | NOT_OK    | CCC
```

Here is the result I expect to have:

```
PRODUCT | STATUS    | DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
--------+-----------+--------------------------------
A       | NOT_OK    | AAA
B       | OK        | BBB
C       | NOT_OK    | CCC
```

---

I tried to use the query below:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, count(STATUS="NOT_OK"), DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY PRODUCT
```

but this is rejected by the error

> missing right parenthesis

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is `DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP` always the same value for the same `PRODUCT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that result, you seem to need a `MIN` more than a `COUNT`; with your data, this

```
select product, min(status), data_product_specific_to_keep
from yourtable
group by product, data_product_specific_to_keep
```

gives:

```
A       NOT_OK      AAA                          
B       OK          BBB                          
C       NOT_OK      CCC
```

If you need to handle more than two values, you have to define a priority logic; you can implement it with something like the following:

```
select PRODUCT,
       case (status)
           when 2 then 'NOT_OK'
           when 1 then 'AWAIT'
           else 'OK'
       end,
       DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
from (
        select min(
                   case (status)
                     when 'NOT_OK' then 2
                     when 'AWAIT' then 1
                     else 0
                   end
                  ) as status,
               PRODUCT, DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
        from yourTable
        group by PRODUCT, DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
)
order by 1
```

With a table like this

```
create table yourTable (PRODUCT, STATUS, DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP) as (
    select 'A', 'NOT_OK', 'AAA' from dual union all
    select 'A', 'OK', 'AAA' from dual union all
    select 'B', 'OK', 'BBB' from dual union all
    select 'B', 'AWAIT', 'BBB' from dual union all
    select 'B', 'OK', 'BBB' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'NOT_OK', 'CCC' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'AWAIT', 'CCC' from dual union all
    select 'D', 'NOT_OK', 'DDD' from dual union all
    select 'D', 'NOT_OK', 'DDD' from dual
)
```

the result would be

```
P CASE(S DAT
- ------ ---
A OK     AAA
B OK     BBB
C AWAIT  CCC
D NOT_OK DDD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works like a charm. Do you know how I could do if I had to select a result that is not the MIN not the MAX ? If I had also a status AWAIT for example ?

Comment: You should define some priority logic; for example, what if a product has an OK and an AWAIT? I guess the logic could be like "if there is at least one OK, give OK, if there is no OK, but there is at least an AWAIT, give AWAIT, otherwise give NOT_OK. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a selective sum  using case for check the right values

```
SELECT PRODUCT, 
       sum(case  STATUS="NOT_OK" then 1 else  0 END), 
       DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY PRODUCT, DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
```

and your group by must include  all the columns not involved  in aggreagation function

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you need a `case` expression there.  But you also need to fix the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT PRODUCT, SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'NOT_OK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as not_ok_cnt, 
       DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY PRODUCT, DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP;
```

All non-aggregated columns need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have two status values... that will do the trick !

```
SELECT t.PRODUCT, MIN(t.STATUS), t.DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
  FROM yourTable t
 GROUP BY t.PRODUCT, t.DATA_PRODUCT_SPECIFIC_TO_KEEP
```

That will extract the minimum string value for each product, and "N" happens to be less than "O" in alphabetical order.